# GPS Accuracy issues in mobile apps

Tags: flutter, gps, fusedlocationproviderclient

i am developing an mobile app [as part of project] which computes live location (using phone gps) every 10 seconds using flutter and native android location libraries and calculates distance of our current location from a fixed gps point (whose latitude and longitude are known). If that distance is less than 10m (given geo radius), then the app will starts a countdown timer.
I used Flutter libraries like geolocator, carp back ground locator and android libraries such as android fused location provider client, location manager to get the gps data and calculates the distance from that fixed gps point , But all these libraries gives inaccurate results
for example, for actual distance of 1m-5m it shows 15m-20m, some times app shows distance of 150m for actual distance of 1m.
I found after googling that theoretically gps has an accuracy of only 5 to 10m (gps.gov) and practically has accuuracy of 15 to 20m (best case), Google map is providing accuracy of 20m (support.google.com), android location library defined a horizontal accuracy of 68%.

Question 1:
Is there any solution for this above mentioned gps inaccuracy issue

Question 2:
When i set interval of 10 second (both native android and flutter) for gps data fetch, this is working in fine in emulator, but in actual phone it runs for 20 seconds (doubling).

i seek help from those who are expert in gps and location libraries in android, flutter

Comment: What happens when you can't get a GPS fix - it happens (sometimes there are buildings in the way)?

Comment: we are actually developing driver console app, when buses arrive at particular stops(determined by the distance between bus and the stop), a timer starts (time for buses to stand at that sop). so but everything is based on gps, if gps not  accurate means whole process not work

Comment: What if the bus has to stop 50m short of the bus-stop, because of construction [it's effectively at the stop]?  Or the data you have for the stops is bad (which is probably quite likely)?